Can I compare data from a 4-point Likert scale and a 5-point Likert scale?
I am planning a policy paper which will compare the policy preferences of the general public in a set of countries, and seek to explain e.g. why some countries tend to strongly approve of ice cream, but not pizza or vice versa. (These are arbitrary examples, the real categories relate to specific policy issues.)
To illustrate my argument, I want to scatter plot the data for each country so that % of ice cream approval is on the x axis, and % of pizza approval is on the y axis.
I have not carried out any surveys myself (this paper is meant to explore the feasibility of undertaking such a project in the future). For now I am using separate surveys on each issue. Both surveys claim to provide representative samples of the population in the countries of interest, and they were carried out at roughly the same time.
The ice cream survey asked participants to indicate approval or disapproval on a 4-point Likert scale without a neutral option; the pizza survey asked participants to indicate approval or disaproval on a 5-point Likert scale with a neutral option.
I want to plot the net approval for each option, by adding together "Strongly approve" and "somewhat approve" for both samples. Of course, since the ice cream survey did not have a neutral option, it might have forced some to pick "somewhat approve" or "somewhat disapprove" instead of the neutral option.
Is there some way to normalize the data in order to make the two data sets comparable, or do I need to do more research to find studies that have the same number of points on their Likert scales?

Your first paragraph is suggestive that there is a deeper causal structure connecting your two rating variables. Defining that structure would be the next step.

Seems to me that if there is a neutral (neither approve nor disapprove) option  in one survey and not the other, then it might be reasonable to assume that the neutral option would split into somewhat approve and somewhat disapprove in proportion to the responses those actual options. Add a note describing the treatment.

I don't see why you think you need to pool any categories. At some point you should present the raw data. If you think some aggregation is needed, then you must make any speculation clear and give the reader scope to analyse the data differently.

It seems like there may be several issues here, in my opinion.

You described, "by adding together 'Strongly approve' and 'somewhat approve' for both samples", which assumes some sort of dichotomization or binarization based on a priori thresholding of the Likert rating scales. However, there are many problems, which have been written about at length, with dichotomizing variables in this manner (see below). More generally, I don't know if you can assume that everyone who respond 3 and 4 on question and 4 and 5 on another question are directly comparable and interpreted the question in the same way.

Negative Consequences of Dichotomizing Continuous Predictor Variables
On the Practice of Dichotomization of Quantitative Variables
The Cost of Dichotomizing Continuous Variables

I also am unclear on how you plan to compare the ratings. It sounds like you are interested in comparing different ratings (one with a 4-point Likert and one with a 5-point Likert) in different samples. If I understand correctly, these ratings will not be provided by the same respondents or in the same sample. I question how or if you can compare these ratings that are about something different, on a different scale, and in a different sample.

There is some evidence in psychometrics that the Likert rating scale can shape response tendencies. For example, a Likert scale without a midpoint may increase tendencies to exhibit extremity response bias, or responding in a more extreme fashion on the rating scale (at the endpoints of the scale for example). As such, even if these scales were about the same topic or question, I would have apprehensions about making some transformation or asssumption about to directly compare them, as I believe there is evidence that the way we design the scales can shape how people respond to the scales, and a 4-point and a 5-point or 7-point Likert will elicit different responses entirely and it's not necessarily the case that the responses are merely transformed or extrapolated in a linear fashion by the respondent, where 5 points will just be the same responses spread out across more points. I’m


Hypothetically, if you were to collect these ratings in the same sample for the same respondents, you could compare responses using an ordinal logistic or non-parametric regression. One potential way to visualize the association between two Likert variables with a different number of levels could be a heatmap where each "tile" denote the proportion of respondents with both X1_i response and X2_i response. Here's a reproducible example:
library(LikertMakeR)

n=500
x1 <- lfast(n, 4, 1.2, 1, 5) 
x2 <- lfast(n, 2.25, 1.2, 1, 4) 

dat <- data.frame(x1, x2) 

cormat <- matrix(
  c(
    1.00, 0.43,
    0.43, 1.00
  ),
  nrow = 2
)

datnew <- lcor(data = dat, target = cormat)
datnew <- cor(datnew) |> round(3)

pdf <- as.data.frame(prop.table(table(df)))

pdf %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X1,y=X2,fill=Freq)) +
  geom_tile(color='black', width=.9, height=.9) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey", high = "red", na.value = NA) +
  theme_classic()


I think another option, although not perfect, could be to use POMP Scores (see here; also described in this Stack Overflow post: POMP score in a bidirectional scale). It is simply:
$$100 * \frac{(Observed - Minimum)}{(Maximum - Minimum)}$$
So if you had a Likert scale with an average of a 3.2, you could say it's POMP score is 55%, as:
$$100 * \frac{(3.2-1)}{(5-1)} = 55$$
This could be a potential way to compare the scores of the two measures, although it's definitely not perfect.
